# nuxt/pwa not working "offline" when deployed to heroku

Tags: heroku, nuxt.js

I am using `Nuxt` in `ssr: false` mode and deploying my app to heroku following [this guide](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/heroku-deployment/).

Now I am using `nuxt/pwa` module which works perfectly fine when testing my app via `npm run build && npm run start` (production mode).

Also I noted this comment from the [nuxt/pwa docu](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/setup/):

> NOTE: If using ssr: false with production mode without nuxt generate,
> you have to use modules instead of buildModules

which I configured correctly so my nuxt.config.js file looks like this:

```js
ssr: false,
...
  modules: [
    ...
    '@nuxtjs/pwa'
  ],

  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      name: 'XY App',
      lang: 'de'
    }
  },
```

Now when the app is deployed to heroku and I turn my phone into flight-mode to simulate offline status, the app is not responding: "You're not connected to the internet" is showing up in the browser.
What do I do wrong here? I cannot see any misconfiguration but maybe I miss something from the PWA approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on how to configure it, but I know that the package itself do not allow a full offline mode by default. Looking at the documentation, it looks like Workbox is doing exactly that. It should be pretty easy to setup and enable a full service-worker + cached pages thanks to it IMO.

https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/workbox

It looks like the starting point is: `yarn add @nuxtjs/workbox`, then fine tuning the configuration!

PS: the rest of your configuration looks nice to me!

Comment: This was working nicely. For npm the command is `npm i --save @nuxtjs/workbox@2.6.0` as the V3 beta is not compatible yet. Also workbox can be configured specifically by GET request that can get cashed which is great.